# TeamCity Agent on linux doesn't recognize Powershell core Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, powershell, teamcity

TC Version : TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1.4 (build 47070)

Linux Version:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

Powershell Core Version: 6.1.2

I'm having some trouble in teamcity getting the build agent to recognize that it has powershell core installed.

I installed the agent under my user account.
Then i installed powershell here https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell

Team city server reports the agent correctly

However i noticed that it couldn't serve powershell requests

Incompatible runner: PowerShell
Unmet requirements: 
Exists=>(powershell_x86|powershell_x64) exists

Looking at the agent logs i get these three lines.

INFO - try.RegistryPowerShellDetector - Detecting PowerShell using RegistryPowerShellDetector

INFO - try.RegistryPowerShellDetector - RegistryPowerShellDetector is only available on Windows

INFO - agent.PowerShellServiceFactory - PowerShell runner is disabled: PowerShell was not found.

Is there something im missing? i've restarted the team cityagent and no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Microsoft changed executable name from powershell to pwsh for PowerShell.Core), TeamCity 2017.1.4 cannot detect powershell presence on the agent machine
The issue was fixed in TeamCity 2017.2, please consider upgrading to a newer TeamCity version (current one is 2018.2.2)

I have backported the fix to 2017.1. To install it, put the attached zip file in /plugins without unpacking and restart the server.
After the restart, please go to Administration -> Plugins List and verify that powershell plugin is external and has version 47176

[powershell.zip](https://jbs.zendesk.com/attachments/token/HzqhgxNJcam7q47CI4KiYcKwE/?name=powershell.zip)

Comment: People are unlikely to want to download content linked here. Can you instead provide a link to an official source for this software?

Comment: The URL for the zip file comes from zendesk for jet brains. I can't do anymore here. however you can raise a ticket yourself.

Answer (score 1):

We managed to get this fixed by an official developer from JetBrains

Follow his instructions here.

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1951317

Comment: Please @Maximilian can you shed some light on what this official developer did? The link is dead, and I seem to run into the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PsiOps, I've added the developers words and the fix, hope this helps.